# Is there a way to find the directory of a file that imports another?

Tags: python

I am looking for a way to find the directory of a file that imports another. This most likely seems very unspecific so, I am going to try to fix that.

Lets say we have a file in a directory named "library.py", and we have another file named "main.py." If in main.py, you import library.py, is the a way to call a function that is in main.py **from library.py**, or is there a way to get the directory to main.py. Either way works.

main.py:

```
import library
def saysom():
    print("something")
    library.dosumthing()
saysom()
```

library.py:

```
def dosumthing():
    #calls a function from main.py without importing main
```

Comment: Do you want to do this when library is _imported_, or when `library.dosumthing()` is _called_?

Answer (score 0):

in your main.py file do this

```
import os
import library

print(os.path.abspath(library.__file__))
```

this will give you the directory to the library.py file

Comment: Forgot to say, is there code I can add to the library.py that senses in someway if it has been imported to another file